# Converting a mp4 into this webM codec with FFMpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, codec

There is a game that uses this weird codec and I wanna know how can I convert my own mp4 file into a webm with using the game's webM settings with FFMpeg or any kind of converter.

Here are the settings for it (from MPC):

```
General
Complete name                  : C:\Users\jesnxe\Desktop\game\extractfile_i\menu\background\bluepink.webm
Format                         : WebM
Format version                 : Version 2
File size                      : 61.9 MiB
Duration                       : 4 min 8 s
Overall bit rate               : 2 094 kb/s
Movie name                     : FX_Ending_Blue Pink
Encoded date                   : UTC 2013-07-29 12:20:34
Writing application            : mkclean 0.8.7 u from Lavf55.0.100
Writing library                : libebml2 v0.21.1 + libmatroska2 v0.22.1
ErrorDetectionType             : Custom

Video
ID                             : 1
Format                         : VP8
Codec ID                       : V_VP8
Duration                       : 4 min 8 s
Bit rate                       : 2 004 kb/s
Width                          : 512 pixels
Height                         : 384 pixels
Display aspect ratio           : 4:3
Frame rate mode                : Constant
Frame rate                     : 25.000 FPS
Compression mode               : Lossy
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)             : 0.408
Stream size                    : 59.3 MiB (96%)
Default                        : Yes
Forced                         : No
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions must demonstrate a reasonable amount of research & understanding of the problem being solved. Please edit to either a) clearly describe your problem and the research done so far to solve it or b) include attempted solutions plus why they didn't work. In either case, be sure your expected results are clearly presented.

Comment: what else do you even want me to add? i asked if i can convert a mp4 into a webm with using lavf's codec. ffmpeg only has that weird vp8 codec. stop voting people's questions randomly, i'm asking for help here. if you don't understand it, then don't even answer to it.

Comment: This is not a free code-writing service. We are here to help you when you have tried something & get stuck. We are not here to google it for you & provide an entire solution for free, just because you couldn't be bothered.

Comment: @Tetsujin i didn't ask anyone to code or do something for me. i know how to use ffmpeg and i asked if anyone knows how can i convert into this format. i didn't tell or force anyone to do something. i just **asked**, do you know what that means? if i knew how to convert into that codec, i wouldn't already be here. where do you even expect me to ask this?

Comment: `bluepink.webm` contains VP8 video. Did you try `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -map 0:v -c:v libvpx output.webm`? For additional options see [FFmpeg Wiki: VP8](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/VP8).

Comment: dude, i already know about converting webm in ffmpeg. that's not what i'm looking for... _sigh_

Comment: Don't call people 'dude'. Don't sigh at people. People are really trying to help you here & you are acting like a **spoilt child**. No-one can see over your shoulder. No-one knows what you know or what you don't. You are asking for someone to hand an entire solution to you on a plate with no hint of any effort whatsoever on your part. Smacks of entitlement.

Comment: I assumed you wanted to encode VP8 video in webm container. Now I'm not sure what the actual question is (because there isn't one).

Comment: @llogan i'm trying to convert my mp4 to webm with using the `mkclean 0.8.7 u from Lavf55.0.100` it's already in the details of the webm i put in the question.

Comment: I have to agree with Tesujin in stating that your question doesn't show a single bit of effort into solving the problem. You say you know converting to WebM in ffmpeg but it's not what you're looking for, but then apparently that's not the point. Please at least [edit] your question to clarify it. Why would you need this particular set of features (mkclean and libavfilter)? Chances are that these aren't really what makes whatever you encode compatible with anything. So what are you actually trying to do with the video?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Encode with `ffmpeg`

25 fps, 512x380, VP8 video:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "fps=25,scale=512:384:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=512:384:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1[v]" -metadata title="FX_Ending_Blue Pink" -c:v libvpx -an video.webm
```

## Run through `mkclean`

```
mkclean video.webm
```

See `mkclean --help` for various options.

This is likely a superfluous step, but you pointed out that you wanted the *Writing application* and *Writing library* to mention this tool.

#### Verbatim madness

If you want the *Writing application* versions to be the same then compile a really old FFmpeg that contains libavformat 55.0.100 (it will be from 2015 or older) and compile mkclean 0.8.7.

Comment: thank you so much! you're the best